# Calculate the effective access time

Tags: cpu-cache, memory-access

This question seems to be causing a lot of debate and I'm wondering whether my working is correct.

> A computer with a single cache (access time 20ns) and main memory (access
> time 500ns) also uses the hard disk (average access time 0.01ms) for virtual
> memory using paging. If it is found that the cache hit rate is 95% and the page
> fault rate is 1%
> Calculate the effective (average) access time (EAT) of this system for a
> sequential access system.
>  
>  (a) 73.5ns. (b) 55ns. (c) 50ns. (d) 74.75ns.

My working was as follows: (0.95x20) + 0.05 (0.01(10000+500+20) + 0.99(500+20))

Leading me to an answer of 50 being C), however others have seem to have chosen D) as their answer

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: `hard disk (average access time 0.01ms)` WHOA! (Or solid state, but the cache access time doesn't look the type.)

Answer (score 0):

Seems correct , cache hit gives you **0.95*20** ns if it misses then 0.05 or 5% of the time you consult memory that is 0.05*( no page fault hence 0.99*( 500 from mem to cache + 20 from cache to cpu) else if page fault occurs then 1% or 0.01 *( 10000 ns from disk to mem +  500 ns from mem to cache + 20 ns from cache to cpu))
Should be 45.5 ns which I would give as C

Answer (score 0):

The problem is a bit unclear, but I would assume that the page fault rate is 1% for *all* accesses, not just for the 5% that didn’t hit the cache. So the total is 0.95 x 20 + 0.04 x X + 0.01 x Y.

Then there is the question how long X or Y are: Many processors will fill a cache line from memory, then access the cache. Total x = 500 + 20. Others might deliver data directly from main memory, X = 500. Similar for Y.

Answer (score 0):

just came across the same question

you need to add an extra 500 to your calculation for accessing the main memory because it actually has to be accessed twice: once for making the page table and another for the actual data, when using virtual memory

(0.95x20) + 0.05 (0.01(10000+500+500+20) + 0.99(500+500+20)) =75 which i would have guessed is closeset to D